# Keep title and text on the same pdf page in xml/xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to keep these 2 entries("blueTitle1" and "content") always on the same page of the pdf output.

my entries look like this:

```
<entry role="blueTitle1">TITLE</entry>
<entry role="content">some text from a paragraph</entry>
```

and the roles look like this:

```
       <xsl:when test="@role = 'blueTitle1'">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@anchor">
                    <xsl:variable name="anchorLink" select="@anchor"/>
                    <fo:block id="{$anchorLink}" font-size="14pt" line-height="13pt" color="#00a6ce" font-family="AvenirNextLTProBold" padding-top="0.7cm">
                        <xsl:apply-templates />
                    </fo:block>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <fo:block font-size="14pt" line-height="13pt" color="#00abd2" font-family="AvenirNextLTProBold" padding-top="0.7cm">
                        <xsl:apply-templates />
                    </fo:block>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>               
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@role = 'content'">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@anchor">
                    <xsl:variable name="anchorLink" select="@anchor"/>
                    <fo:block id="{$anchorLink}" font-size="10.5pt" line-height="12.5pt" padding-top="0.35cm">
                        <xsl:apply-templates />
                    </fo:block>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <fo:block font-size="10.5pt" line-height="12.5pt" padding-top="0.35cm">
                        <xsl:apply-templates />
                    </fo:block>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>               
        </xsl:when>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap both elements in an `fo:block` with [page-break-inside](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#page-break-inside) attribute set to "avoid".

```
<fo:block page-break-inside="avoid">
  ...
</fo:block>
```

Or, if you don't wrap it in an `fo:block`, the following elements can handle the `page-break-inside` attribute:

- fo:basic-link
- fo:block
- fo:block-container
- fo:inline
- fo:inline-container
- fo:list-block
- fo:list-item
- fo:list-item-body
- fo:list-item-label
- fo:table
- fo:table-and-caption
- fo:table-caption
- fo:table-row